# Why does F# complain that a function is not defined?

Tags: f#, undefined

Why does compiler complain that MyAdd is not defined?

```
type MyTest = 
    static member MyAdd (y1 : int, y2 : int) = y1 + y2
    static member Test (x1 : int, x2 : int) = 
        let Z = MyAdd (x1,x2)
        0.0
```

Comment: So I see you are from C# world, where class name is optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the type when calling a static member:

```
let Z = MyTest.MyAdd (x1,x2)
```

Types can't "be open" like modules or namespaces. Members are called via dot-notation:

- `instance.MyMember` for instance members
- `MyType.MyStaticMember` for static members.